# Creating a single unit of time (minute, week etc) with ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, activesupport

With ActiveSupport's [extensions to Numeric](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time), one can write the following to obtain two minutes: `2.minutes`.

There are some situations, though, where only a few time units are important. Suppose there's a task that your application can run every **one** day, week, or month, depending on some input:

```
@frequency = :day # can be any of the following: [:day, :month, :week]
```

Using ActiveSupport's extensions to Numeric naively, we could do this to determine when to run the task:

```
def run_every
  1.send(@frequency)
end
```

Which will call the [`days`](http://apidock.com/rails/Numeric/days) instance method in `Numeric` (the `day` method is an alias).

In this scenario we're only interested in **one** minute, day, week, month, year, etc. Is there a nicer way to instantiate a single unit of time other than the one I described?

Comment: "minute" is a *unit* of time, whereas "1 minute" is a *duration*. Are you sure that you want `1.minute` and not just `:minute`?

Comment: @Stefan that's perfectly right, and yes I'm sure. I'm using this frequency to schedule something for later execution (Sidekiq's `perform_in`, which takes a `Time` or a `Duration`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # can be any of the following: [:day, :month, :week]
> ```

I'd use a hash instead, something like:

```
DURATIONS = { day: 1.day, week: 1.week, month: 1.month }.freeze

def run_every
  DURATIONS[@frequency]
end
```

Comment: Can you explain why ? Is it faster than using send because of the freeze, or something ?

Comment: @Caillou `freeze` is just to prevent changes. I try to avoid `send` / `public_send` in general, because it can delegate arbitrary messages that may result in hard-to-track bugs. Using an explicit hash allows me to control the method's return value. `run_every` either returns a `ActiveSupport::Duration` or `nil`.

Comment: I see. Then we could use both tricks to create something like `DURATION = [:day, :week, :year]` and use it as a validation of the frequency, while still calling send to create the duration.

Comment: I ended up using something close to @Stefan's solution. On a somewhat-related note, it is good practice to add some kind of namespace in this situation (e.g. `:every_day` instead of just `:day`), particularly when `send` is involved and even more when you're using things like `ActiveRecord` (which wasn't the case in my example, but is the case in my real use case).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : This answer only says "you got it right"

It seems to be a pretty fair use of the `send` method : You have to get a time unit depending on a frequency (day, month, year), so using `send` on a Numeric with the frequency as the method name seems to me like the perfect use case of `send`.

EDIT : As Jordan said, you should just use `public_send` instead of `send`, as a good habit. It's because you can access private methods with `send`, which is usually not recommended.

Comment: One should use `public_send` instead of `send` (just as a good habit), but otherwise I agree. Looking at the source of ActiveSupport's [Numeric](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb) extensions and [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb) we can see that there isn't a cleaner way to instantiate a Duration.

Comment: I agree. I'm editing the answer with precisions about `public_send`.